# validation of radiobuttonlist in asp.net using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have to validate a radio button using javascript. it should show a message if none of the option is selected.

my radio button code is:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="welldata" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="100px">
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

and the submit button is:

```
<asp:Button ID="next2" runat="server" Text=">>" Width="46px" 
        OnClientClick="return next2()"/>
```

the corresponding javascript function is :

```
        function next2() {

        var listItemArray = document.getElementById('<%=welldata.ClientID %>');
        var isItemChecked = false;
        var length1 = listItemArray.length;

        for (var i=0; i<length1; i++)
          {
              var listItem = listItemArray[i];
              document.write(listItem);

             if ( listItem.checked )
                 {
               alert(listItem.value);
               isItemChecked = true;
                 }
           }

            if ( isItemChecked == false )
              {
              alert('Nothing is checked for welldata!');

              return false;
                 }

             return true;
    }
```

while debugging i noticed thaat function is executed but doesn't enter the for loop.
also i tried

```
        document.write(isItemChecked);
        document.write(listItemArray);
        document.write(length1);
```

and the output was :

> false [object HTMLTableElement] undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wellData` `RadioButtonList` ASP.NET server control will render in the browser as a table with a number of `input type="radio"` controls under it, each with the same `name`.

So, you need to get the `input` tags inside the `table` tag first:

```
var wellData = document.getElementById('<%=welldata.ClientID %>');
var listItemArray = wellData.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

This is, of course, if you are doing this manually for some odd reason. You can do it automatically with a `RequiredFieldValidator` control.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="welldata" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="100px">
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvWellData" runat="server" ControlToValidate="wellData" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Pick yourself some well data" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a RadiobuttonList which is rendered as table per default. If you select the dom element by id `document.getElementById('<%=welldata.ClientID %>')` then you are selecting the table and not the RadioButtonList. If you want to select the radio buttons then you have to loop through the childNodes of `listItemArray` to get the radio buttons. Alternatively you could use jquery to select the radio buttons, as their ids will start with the id of your radio button list (they will look like `welldata_0` or `welldata_1`).

This line of jquery code will get the your radio buttons

```
var listItemArray = $("input[id^='welldata']")
```

Comment: You would not want to use a 'starts with' query with the hardcoded ID, because if you are inside a master page, the ID of the `ContentPlaceHolder` tag will be prepended to the IDs of all tags. You would want to use something like `<%= String.Format("$(\"input[id^='{0}']\")", wellData.ClientID) %>`

Comment: In case of master pages of user controls I would rather use `$("input[id*='welldata_']")`.

Comment: sorry brother. No jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function next2() {

        if(document.getElementById('<%=welldata.ClientID %>').checked==false)
{
alert('Nothing is checked for welldata!');
return false;
}
return true;
}
                   or
```

Use `RequiredFieldValidator`

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator   
            ID="ReqiredFieldValidator1"  
            runat="server"  
            ControlToValidate="welldata"  
            ErrorMessage="Select your welldata!"  
            >
```

Check these below links

http://asp-net-example.blogspot.in/2009/02/aspnet-requiredfieldvalidator-example.html

http://www.itechies.net/tutorials/jscript/jsexample.php-pid-jform.htm#rb

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/499602/RequiredplusFieldplusValidatorplusForplusRadioplus

Comment: `document.getElementById('<%=welldata.ClientID %>')` selects the rendered table and not the radio buttons.

Comment: Hmm. Try RequiredFieldValidator

Answer (score 0):

```
var rblItems = document.getElementById('<%=radioBtnListId.ClientID %>').getElementsByTagName('input');

var checkedItems = true;
for (var i = 0; i < rblItems.length; i++) {
    if (rblItems[i].checked) {
        checkedItems = true;
        break;
    }
    else {
        checkedItems = false;
    }
}

if (!checkedItems) {//Hence No items checked
   alert("Nothing is checked");
   return false; 
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question he/she want to validate the radio button list whether the any of option is checked or not. so I'm getting the properties of the radio button list by using the id. So in the rblItems variable i can get all options in rbl. From that I'm using for loop to check each option is checked or not. If the any option is checked I'm setting the variable checkedItems as true and breaking loop. Then if checkedItems is true, we can found that one of the option is checked. Hope this make sense.

Comment: Add this in answer instead of comment.