# asp:RadioButtonList asp:RequiredFieldValidator Never fires the validation

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a webforms page (don't ask) that I am trying to get some client side validation working on, using the standard validators.

Heres some partial code

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="50px" HeaderText="Received">
        <HeaderStyle  HorizontalAlign="Center" />
               <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbIsRecv"  RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
                      runat="server" ValidationGroup="Curriculum">
                       <asp:ListItem Value="1">Yes&nbsp;</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">No</asp:ListItem>
                     </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
                   ControlToValidate="rbIsRecv" Text="Required" 
                    ValidationGroup="Curriculum" />
          </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

<.......>

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="50px" HeaderText="Actually Received">
                                <HeaderStyle  HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtActual" runat="server" />  
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="AllValidators" runat="server" 
                                        ControlToValidate="txtActual" ErrorMessage="All values must be filled in!" />                                 
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                    </div>
                </div>          
            </div>
             <div class="row pull-right">
                <asp:Label runat="server">Employee ID: </asp:Label> 
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" /><br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" CssClass="btn-primary pull-right" />
            </div>  
            <div class="row">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="AllValidators" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName" ErrorMessage="Please enter your employee Number!" />     
                <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AllValidators"/>
            </div>
```

So when I submit it throws and error to the Summary Control from the txtName control properly, but none of the controls within the grids....

Any ideas?

Comment: There is an answer for validation using <asp:RequiredFieldValidator> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349532/validation-of-radiobuttonlist-in-asp-net-using-javascript

`<asp:RadioButtonList ID="welldata" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="100px">
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvWellData" runat="server" ControlToValidate="wellData" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Pick yourself some well data" />`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot validate a `RadioButtonList` with a `RequiredFieldValidator`. You need a `CustomValidator` for that.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Select an option"
    ClientValidationFunction="validateRadioButtonList"></asp:CustomValidator>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateRadioButtonList(oSrc, args) {
        if ($("input[name='<%= RadioButtonList1.UniqueID %>']:checked").val() == null) {
            args.IsValid = false;
        } else {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```